# Countdown in alertDialog Android Studio

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, countdowntimer

I researched some code for countdown on AlertDialog but when I tried the code its not counting down its just show the time tha when its clicked but when it is clicked again it is ticked but I wanted it to be inside the dialog box when its counting down. Well here is my code.

```
fabTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(downPaymentActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Time left");
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Manila");
                sdf1.setTimeZone(tz);
                String currentDateandTime = sdf1.format(new Date());

                String givenDateString = tvDueDate.getText().toString();

                Date date1 = sdf1.parse(currentDateandTime);
                Date date2 = sdf1.parse(givenDateString);

                long restDatesinMillis = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
                final String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(restDatesinMillis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(restDatesinMillis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(restDatesinMillis)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(restDatesinMillis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(restDatesinMillis)));
                builder.setMessage(hms);
                new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long l) {
                        builder.setMessage(hms + (l/1000));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                }.start();
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of setting message to Builder dynamically , set message to AlertDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `AlertDialog` like this

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Time left");
builder.setMessage("start time");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.cancel();
    }
});

final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        alert.setMessage("left: "+l);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        alert.setMessage("end");
    }
}.start();
```

[image]

Comment: 2 alert dialogs are showing sir the first one needs to be OK'ed so the actual timer will be shown

Comment: So foolish of me sir. I didn't saw the `builder.create();` part of the code. I just made some changes and it works perfectly!

Comment: @JaredBrylle awesome. if you have some problem with this cowndown dialog, please notify me ;)

Answer (score 0):

The builder and the dialog are two separate entities. Your timer is setting the message for the builder *after* the dialog has already been built.

You should keep a reference to what's returned by:

```
builder.show();
```

And then call `setMessage()` on that.

Also, don't forget to cancel the timer when your dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for count down time in your alert dialog box its working

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```